# Returning previous activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hı guys.I have a problem in Android.

I have 2 activity which is called **MainActivity** and **Main2Activity**.

I can reach Main2Activity when İ click the button with following code

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In `Main2Activity, there is a button but when I click the button, it will not execute. Actually, after I wrote the following code, when I click the button in MainActivity, it stops execute, I cannot reach second activity

What I want to do is return `MainActivity`. Please help? Do you have any idea?

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an NPE?

Comment: Emulator stops working when i click the first button,I can not reach Main2activity

Comment: What is the error in your Logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get reference of button in Main2Activity

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

and then

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```